# Stop and Wait retransmission of packets?

Tags: computer-networks

In a communication link out of p packets one packet will be lost. If stop and wait protocol is used then expected number of retransmissions for a packet?

(A) P/(1-P)

(B) P

(C) 1/(1-P)

(D) 1/P

I am getting option a) as answer. Anyway to solve this?

Comment: Is P same as the number of p packets? If so, it doesn't make sense since 1-P is a negative number.

Comment: No, P is total packets and p packets out of these P we are sending!

Comment: I become more confused after your reply to @BanghuaZhao. Either I am crazy or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the probability that a packet is lost is $1/p$. Then the number of packets you need to send until the packet is sent successfully is a geometric random variable with success probability $1-1/p$. Hence the expected number of packets you need to send is $1/(1-1/p) = p/(p-1)$. The expected number of *re*transmissions is $p/(p-1) - 1 = 1/(p-1)$. So none of the answers is correct.